# No shadow if edges are rounded on NSView

Tags: cocoa, nsview, rounding, dropshadow

I'm trying to round and drop shadow from one NSView derived class with following code:

```
   [graphHostView setWantsLayer:YES];


    graphHostView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
    graphHostView.layer.shadowOffset = NSMakeSize(10.0f, -10.0f);
    graphHostView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;


    graphHostView.layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;
    graphHostView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;    
    graphHostView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    [graphHostView.layer setNeedsLayout];
```

Shadowing is working only if there is no rounding and it doesn't matter if rounding comes first or second. I can also drop shadow indirectly from view with code:

NSShadow *myShadow = [[NSShadow alloc]init];
[myShadow setShadowOffset:NSMakeSize(10.0f, -10.0f)];
[myShadow setShadowBlurRadius:3.0];
[graphHostView setShadow:myShadow];
[myShadow set];

with completely same effect. I have tried all combinations of display, setNeedsLayout and other properties and methods and nothing works.

It seems unbelievably to me, that this doesn't work, after all, NSWindow is rounded and shadowed...

Being reminded I have to add that I have tried to apply shadow also on backing layer with same result. 
Since masksToBounds would expectedly mask anything outside the bounds, it is reasonably to believe that shadow cannot be displayed on same layer. 
It is also clear, that masking has effect on anything that could be add to this layer also later, after the masking, since order of setting the shadow and mask does not have and effect on result.

So, question is still, how to achieve wanted result without driving another NSView below with shadow if this is possible at all?

Comment: Does masksToBounds prevent the drawing of your shadow (since it is outside the bounds?)

Answer (score 2):

This did it for me (in Swift):

graphHostView.layer.masksToBounds = false

Answer (score -2):

You need:

```
[[graphHostView superview] setWantsLayer:YES];
```